# Validating form with Model State on Client Side in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I am trying to validate the form on button click. As Form (view) is bounded with Model and model properties are wrapped with `Data-Annotations`, so before any other action, I want to validate the form with jQuery.

```
$("#btnSubNext,#btnSubLast").on('click', function () {
        $("#myform").validate();
        if ($('#myform').valid()) {

        }
    });
```

But it is not working properly.

Note:  `myform` is `id` of form as mentioned below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CCEAddUpdateScheduleA", "CCESchedule", FormMethod.Post, new { 
@id = "myForm", @name = "myForm", @class = "myForm" }))
    {.....
}
```

Comment: what is not working properly? Are you getting any error? Or facing any behavior issue?

Comment: Above code is not validating the form.

Comment: what if statement returns? true or false?

Comment: unable to Identify...as I debugging it with debugger;...cursor of debugger is not going inside of code...its escaping after  if ($('#myform').valid())

Comment: If it is not going inside if statement that means your form is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled as true in Web.config? You also need jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobstrusive. Check http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript